# How to get AdGroupAuthProvider worked with OrmLiteCacheClient?

Tags: c#, session, active-directory, servicestack, sql-session-state

I want that application will be accessible for end user regardless on which server node LoadBalancer redirects.
So, I would like to use OrmLiteCacheClient to store session in MSSQL DB.

I have the following code (there is only part of SetupPlugins):

```
private void SetupPlugins (Container container)
{
    //Register OrmLite Db Factory if not already
    container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(c =>
        new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(connString, SqlServerDialect.Provider));

    container.RegisterAs<OrmLiteCacheClient, ICacheClient>();

    //Create 'CacheEntry' RDBMS table if it doesn't exist already
    container.Resolve<ICacheClient>().InitSchema();

    container.Register<IAuthRepository>(c =>
        new OrmLiteAuthRepository(c.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>()));

    container.Resolve<IAuthRepository>().InitSchema();

    Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(), new IAuthProvider[] {
        new AdGroupAuthProvider(container.Resolve<IActiveDirectoryAuthHelper>(),
        GlobalConfiguration.Instance.AllowedActiveDirectoryGroup)
    }));       
}

internal class AdGroupAuthProvider : BasicAuthProvider
{
    private readonly IActiveDirectoryAuthHelper _adLoggingHelper;
    private readonly string _loggedUserAdGroup;

    public AdGroupAuthProvider(IActiveDirectoryAuthHelper loggingHelper,     string loggedUserAdGroup)
    {
        _adLoggingHelper = loggingHelper;
        _loggedUserAdGroup = loggedUserAdGroup;
    }
    public override bool Authenticate(IServiceBase loggingServiceBase,     string userName, string password)
    {
        return _adLoggingHelper.HasUserAssignedGroup(userName, password, _loggedUserAdGroup);
    }
 }
}
```

How to get AdGroupAuthProvider worked with OrmLiteCacheClient?
The above programme builds and I can authenticate. 
However, the CacheEntry MSSQL table is empty.

Answer (score 0):

ServiceStack uses `ICacheClient` to store [User Sessions](https://docs.servicestack.net/sessions) in normal [session-based Auth Providers](https://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization#session-authentication-overview) although it does not persist Sessions to the Cache in [IAuthWithRequest Providers](https://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization#authentication-per-request-auth-providers).

I'm not familiar with `AdGroupAuthProvider` but if it implements `IAuthWithRequest` the request contains the authentication per request which is what's used to populate the session that's only attached to the Request and not persisted in the `ICacheClient`.

Comment: Hi Mythz, thank you for the answer. 
Please find AdGroupAuthProvider in the above post (just edited),

Comment: @essential [BasicAuthProvider](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Auth/BasicAuthProvider.cs#L7) is an `IAuthWithRequest` provider, if you didn't want that maybe you'd want to inherit from [CredentialsAuthProvider](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Auth/CredentialsAuthProvider.cs) instead like the [example Custom Auth Provider](https://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization#custom-authentication-and-authorization) in the auth docs.

Comment: I added inheritance from CredentialsAuthProvider. 
What should I do to get basic-auth working with ActiveDirectory and store session in DB?

Comment: @essential What Basic Auth? I can't tell you how this Auth Provider should authenticate. If you want to inspect the current request you can access it from `loggingServiceBase.Request` although it shouldn't be called `loggingServiceBase` as it's the `authService` Service class, i.e. it's not a dependency from the IOC.

Comment: @essential As mentioned, if your Auth Provider doesn't implement `IAuthWithRequest` then it will save the session to the registered ICacheClient provided that if you override `OnAuthenticated()` in [your Custom CredentialsAuthProvider](https://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization#custom-authentication-and-authorization) that you also call `base.OnAuthenticated()` which is where the session gets saved, if you don't override `OnAuthenticated()` the base method gets called automatically.

Comment: It doesn't implement `IAuthWithRequest`, so the above code should resolve the case, am I right?
If so, could you please tell how I can test if it's really working?

I ran the app with above code, opened swagger-ui, clicked _Try it out_ , then it prompted for credentials.
In the background I had opened SQL Server Profiler and I could see some queries are executed by the app.
But, there aren't any records in the SQL tables: CacheEntry, UserAuth, UserAuthDetails, UserAuthRole

Comment: @essential Test it by actually using it, only the BasicAuthProvider does HTTP Basic Auth which triggers Username/Password prompt. If you're authenticating with Username/Password you would make a POST request to `/auth/{provider}` (e.g. /auth/credentials) with populated Username/Password fields. The fields could either be populated from a normal Service Request or HTML Form Post, that's up to you.